# Why does my notification show every time I open my Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, notifications

I set up this code (or so I thought) to display a Notification once every 7 days on a user's Android device, even if the user reboots their device. But what I'm seeing as a side-effect is that every time the user opens the app it also pops that notification.

How can I set this up so that the notifications get set up properly, even after reboot, but doesn't display until the required time.

I have a `MainActivity` with this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  val bootRec = BootReceiver()
  bootRec.scheduleNotifications(this)
}
```

It calls `BootReceiver` with this:

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
            scheduleNotifications(context)
        }
    }

    fun scheduleNotifications(context: Context) {
        val receiver = ComponentName(context, BootReceiver::class.java)

        context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )

        val alarmMgr: AlarmManager?

        alarmMgr = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val alarmIntent: PendingIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
        }

        // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13)
        }

        // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
        // 1 week.
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
            alarmIntent
        )
    }
}
```

which in turn calls `AlarmReceiver`:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notChanId = "icollecteverything"
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(notChanId, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
            notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000)
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        val intentMain = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentMain, 0)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notChanId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Notification Text.")
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("Notification Text."))
            .build()
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)
    }

}
```

The `AndroidManifest` has this in it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".helper.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>
<receiver android:name=".helper.BootReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I don't know kotlin, but from trying to figure out your code I think I can see the problem. When ever you open your app you define a notification and then set it to 1 week ahead. The next time you open the application you are not checking if there's a pending notification and you simply repeat the process

Comment: Pretty sure the notification channel and id prevent this: `val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(notChanId, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)` Besides, it's happening on the first run of the app. I think it's from `notificationManager.notify(1, notification)` getting called but I don't know why it is before the alarm is triggered.

Comment: It prevents it while device is running. After a reboot it creates a new one. First time you run, notification shows. Second time, it is updated due to using same ID. After device reboot, there's no notification to update so it's creating a new one

Comment: Probably due to `timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()`, Could you replace it with `set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [the documentation on `AlarmManager.setRepeating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))?

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, **the alarm will be triggered immediately**, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

I suspect this is the root of your problem.

If so, the solution would thus be making sure that `triggerAtMillis` is set to a time in the future. Probably feasibly through some additional/different `Calendar` calls.

Comment: Ahh I missed that! I'll mess with that and see if that's the issue. Thanks.